# How to make the alignment

Tags: javascript

please refer the below code.Here I have to change the position of button to left of the textbox and right of the textbox dynamically

```
<input type="text" id="textbox"/>
<input type="button" id="btn"/>
```

Comment: I should be doable with the css property `float` set to `left` or `right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" style='float:left;'/>
<input type="button" id="btn" style='float:right;'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use 'style' property

`document.getElementById("btn").style.float = 'left';`